# React native - Where is the Dev Settings in IOS? How to change the server host?

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to change the debug server host in IOS, but not found the Dev Menu in IOS.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
You Can Check GitHub Issue : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1429

Once port get Change you Can start just like  `react-native start --port=8088`

Comment: Do you know if there's any way you can do this dynamically? It was better not to have the fixed ip, because it can change.